# create JDBC connection in EcelipseLInk application

Tags: jdbc, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am try retreive java.sql.Connection in Eclipselink Application running on glassfish.

```
Connection cnn = ((JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getAccessor().getConnection();
Connection cnn = ((EntityManagerImpl)(em.getDelegate())).getServerSession().getAccessor().getConnection();
Connection cnn = (Connection) em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

But in all cases i get cnn == null.

Netbeanse/Ecelipselink v 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are connected.

The last method is the correct one.  Ensure that you begin a transaction first.